# anchorScroll does not execute in controller with ng-repeat?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, anchor-scroll

I think I have identified some odd AngularJS1 behaviour concerning the timing of ng-repeat running and therefore conflicting with the timing of controller execution.

My controller automatically scrolls down to an html anchor ID:
$anchorScroll('html_id');

This works fine with static html ([static html plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lRJ4YmDzC3rgSk39ounz?p=preview))

```html
<div id="hello1">Hello1 </div>
```

But anchorScroll doesnt seem to work if it is called by the controller on divs generated by ng-repeat ([ng-repeat plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ArkJTg0sg884nGBOPvmY?p=preview))

```html
 <div id="{{ITEM.slug}}" ng-repeat="ITEM in LIST">{{ITEM.slug}}</div>
```

NOTE:: anchorScroll on ng-repeat works fine with a button but I want it to scroll automatically ON LOADING...

(I have also tried usig ng-init= to call a scroll function, but same timing problem - so it cant find the anchor... even if coded AFTER the ng-repeat)

Any ideas / workarounds?

(there doesnt seem to be any ng-repeat events to bind to...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, `$anchorScroll` has to execute *after* the digest cycle, so that the items have actually been rendered.

The easiest way to make this happen is to use `$timeout` with a `0` second delay, which creates a promise that will be resolved.  With the `0` delay, the promise will be handled after the *current* digest cycle completes, instead of being handled immediately.

```
testApp.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $anchorScroll, $timeout) {
  $scope.LIST = [{
    "slug": "hello1"
  }, {
    "slug": 'hello2'
  }, {
    "slug": 'hello3'
  }];

  $timeout(function() {
    $anchorScroll('hello3');
  }, 0);
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/53hlGNig7eozlm1vqkQL?p=preview

Comment: You're a star!  Nice clean solution - exactly what I was looking for - Thanks :)